# How to nest a component wrapping a stack navigator inside a tab navigator react

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Current Behavior
I am trying to have a tab navigator, where one of the screens/tabs has a component, that, among other stuff, has a stack navigator in it.
However, I currently get a 'No "routes" found in navigation state' error.

How to reproduce
The code I'm currently running can also be found as a snack.
Code:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'A',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Screen A</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsHome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreenA')}>
        <Text>Navigate to Settings A</Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreenA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Settings A</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsA')}>
          <Text>Back to SettingsHome</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SettingsStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SettingsHome: { screen: SettingsHome },
  SettingsScreenA: { screen: SettingsScreenA }
})

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Some other components...</Text>
        <SettingsStackNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen },
});

const Navigation = createAppContainer(RootTabNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigation />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u share it on http://snack.expo.io?

Answer (score 0):

in this button you want to navigate to `SettingsA`

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsA')}>
          <Text>Back to SettingsHome</Text>
        </Button>
```

but you defined the route of Settings screen as `Settings`

```
const RootTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen },
});
```

you have to fix it by change the SettingsA as route name in tab navigator

```
const RootTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  SettingsA: {screen: SettingsScreen },
});
```